# Bind object to input field Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to bind a Company object from my component to my view. This was easy in AngularJS, but I get an error when I do this in Angular 2.

View

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="company.name" 
    placeholder="Company Name" required>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="company.address1" 
    placeholder="Address Line 1" id="address1" required>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right next-btn" (click)="show()">Next</button>
```

Component:

```
company: Company;

constructor(
  private router: Router
 ) { }

ngOnInit() { }

show() {
  console.log(this.company);
}
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This should work , its correct any error have you imported the Forms Module for ngModule

Comment: When you ask for help with an error, always post the error. You wouldn't call a doctor and say "something is wrong. tell me how to get better" and expect her to be able to help ;-)

Comment: I updated the question with error, sorry about that guys.

Comment: @RahulSingh I did not import the NgForm module, which solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rahul said I had to import NgForm from the @angular/forms module for it to work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ngModel` out of the form then you must set options to `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`, if you have from, then you must set `name` attribute for each control.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying with Template Driven forms, If you are interested on Reactive Form please see the below site
https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive

Good luck!

You can use the below code for your (Template Driven Form) reference.

```
<code>
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
      <div>Username:        <input type="text"     name="username" ngModel></div>
      <div>SSN:             <input type="text"     name="ssn"      ngModel></div>
      <div>Password:        <input type="password" name="password" ngModel></div>
      <div>Confirm password: <input type="password" name="pconfirm"  ngModel></div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  `
})
class AppComponent {
  onSubmit(formData) {
    console.log(formData);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports     : [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap   : [ AppComponent ]
})
class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

<input type="text" value="{{ company.name | async}}" placeholder="filter by server status" [(ngModel)]="company.name">